# JSON to array in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a very long JSON format (I quoted something partially below).
I want to convert to an Array in PHP.

Why does `json_decode` return null?

```js
{
  "pages": [{
    'o': true,
    'pid': 12012143,
    'gid': '231efb82-ac2e-446f-ac20-3466b8341e12',
    'lcl': 'C1',
    'v': 22,
    'hi': 113,
    'w': 629
  }, {
    'o': true,
    'pid': 22013354,
    'gid': '22412456-141b-4e4d-a720-c036c3783722',
    'lbl': 'C2',
    'v': 22,
    'hi': 113,
    'w': 629
  }]
}
```

Comment: Because it's not valid JSON. Keys and values belong in double quotes.

Comment: Use http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com to validate your json.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes are not valid [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Change them all to double quotes and it should parse fine.

Comment: how can i covert single quotes to  double quotes in my case
Only automatically(with function)